# .wmv videos in HTML5 Videp player in IE10

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, html5-video, codec

Is there any way, to make .wmv videos play in HTML5 video player. The browser that I am targeting is only and only IE10.
Any add-on, custom code would also do.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Browser_support

You'll need to use Theora or VP8 for standard video codec and then H.264 for fallback for non-standard codec support in Internet Explorer and Safari which (Microsoft and Apple) have fought against open-source standards which the web was based upon.

I really hope your *source* isn't WMV.